# jQuery 1.7.1 slider not working except on homepage

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, slider

I have tried to place the slider on every page on this website: http://atripathi.com

It works on the homepage, but doesn't work on any of the other pages (About, Services, etc.)

I know it's probably an easy fix, but I can't get it at the moment.

Thank you for any help or suggestions!

Comment: you need to include the plugin on the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the original suggestion above is correct.  I'm seeing slider javascript includes at the top of your homepage that aren't on the other pages.

Generally, a good way of troubleshooting is to make copies of both pages, index-c.php and about-c.php perhaps, and start removing everything that isn't pertinent to the trouble you're having (other HTML, css includes, etc.) until you get down to only the slider on the page.  Once you've done that, you might notice that the one page is slightly different than the other, making it work.  You can copy back and forth until it does.

The other possibility is that there's a relative path problem somewhere, because your one page is inside a folder (though I'm guessing you have a .htaccess redirect to a root folder page)?  So if all else fails, move the reduced about-c.php to the root folder and see if that then works.  If so, you know it's a path problem.

Hope these suggestions help.

Comment: Thanks man! Love you :*
I was able to figure out the error when I searched for 'script' in Chrome's Inspector and found the 2 files which weren't included in the other pages. Adding this solved the problem:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://atripathi.com/wp-content/themes/u-design/sliders/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.min.js?ver=2.86"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://atripathi.com/wp-content/themes/u-design/sliders/cycle/cycle1/cycle1_script.js?ver=1.0.0"></script>

Answer (score 0):

I see that jQuery is being included on all your pages but the cycle plugin is only included on the home page. You should be able to update your template(s) to fix this.